# Disable right click on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am using canvas with html to draw on the screen. The thing I need is to draw with the left click only, and right click just do nothing. I tried the following:

```
canvas.oncontextmenu = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

It disabled the right click menu, but I am able to press the canvas (and eventually draw on it) with both left and right click. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
<canvas oncontextmenu="return false;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Let me try  it:)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
canvas.bind('contextmenu', function(e){
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using Jquery:**

```
$('body').on('contextmenu', '#myCanvas', function(e){ return false; });
```

Comment: When you post a reply, explain a little bit, even if right. In your case, there are more answers so you should expose the Pros and Cons of your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  if (event.which !== 1) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

It should also disable context menu from appearing. Clicking the middle mouse button won't give any effect too.

`event.which` contains the index of mouse button that is pressed. `1` is the left button, `2` is the middle, `3` is the right one.
`preventDefault()` prevents default browser behaviour from being executed (such as opening context menu etc, it can be applied in many situations).

By the way, `stopPropagation()` is used to stop such events (as context menu opening, in this case) from being executed at *child elements*. `<canvas>` doesn't have child tags, so it can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
canvas.oncontextmenu = () => false;
```

where **myCanvas** is eventually the ID given to the canvas, i.e.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```